# How to clear Navigation in Xamarin/MAUI?

Tags: xamarin, maui

I have the following app structure:

```
Main Page : Choose Login Type A or B

if the user choses login type A then navigate to > Page A1 Credentials for A type
if the user choses login type B then navigate to > Page B1 Credentials for B type

if Login is successful for page A1 navigate to > Page A2
if Login is successful for page B1 navigate to > Page B2


            Page A1 --- Login Successful ---> Page A2
          /
         /
        /
Page 1  \
         \
          \
            Page B1 --- Login Successful ---> Page B2
```

If the user is in Page A1 or B1, I would like to allow him to go back to page 1 if he wants. However if the user logs in either using type 1 or 2 and reaches either A2 or B2, he shouldn't be allowed to go back.

Here is my code:

Before going to pages A2 or B2 I run. (This code executes in pages A1, B1):

```
public static void RemoveAllPagesFromNavigation(INavigation Navigation)
    {
        var existingPages = Navigation.NavigationStack.ToList();
        foreach (var page in existingPages)
        {
            if (page != null)
            {
                Navigation.RemovePage(page);
            }
        }
    }

RemoveAllPagesFromNavigation(this.Navigation);
await Navigation.PushAsync(new PageA2());       // Or PageB2
```

But the function **RemoveAllPagesFromNavigation** raises an exception saying that the first element of the NavigationStack is null;

I added a condition to skip the case where the first page is null, the function runs but the end user is still able to go back to page Page 1.

How can I prevent user from going back to the pages 1, A1 or B2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Shell navigation / Absolute routes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation?view=net-maui-7.0#absolute-routes), the use of `//` at beginning of a route will **replace** the current nav stack. Thus there will be nowhere to go back to.

```cs
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//Page2");
```

---

FYI ALTERNATIVE:

There is an alternative navigation paradigm, [NavigationPage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/pages/navigationpage) that lacks appshell features such as "Routes". Advantage is simple, direct, programmatic control over the navigation stack. (Without the subtleties that AppShell introduces. One of which you have encountered.)

Consider using `NavigationPage` during the login sequence, only going to AppShell once user is in your main content. (Or omit AppShell completely, just use NavigationPage for your app.)

To do so, in App.xaml.cs, replace:
`MainPage = new AppShell();`
with:
`MainPage = new NavigationPage();`.

Then use `NavigationPage` features to show first login page, etc. Don't use anything from that AppShell navigation doc I linked earlier.

If after login success, you want to use AppShell navigation, do:
`Application.Current.MainPage = new AppShell();`.

---

THIRD ALTERNATIVE:

Do `Application.Current.MainPage = new MyNextFascinatingPage();` to step through the login sequence. Thus there is nowhere for user to go back to, during these steps. (If you want them to go back, you do so explicitly, by creating a `new` copy of earlier page.)

After login success, do:
`Application.Current.MainPage = new AppShell();`.

Comment: I'm not sure this answer is factually correct, at least in the first part and in MAUI. I exclusively use `GoToAsync`, and all of my pages still have back arrows on both Windows and Android, which is explicitly why I'm looking for a solution to this. I haven't yet attempted either of the other alternatives, but I just wanted to share that this might need an edit.

Comment: You are right. Shell uses GoToAsync for all its forward navigation; PushAsync is a NavigationPage command; question asker shouldn't have been using it. My explanation about what was on nav stack was (I think) correct; but using GoToAsync wouldn't remove back arrow. I'll edit.

Comment: Ha, that works! It should be noted that, at least if you're using App Shell, you need to have the destination page defined in the App Shell XAML (or, I assume, in the code-behind), or you get an exception related to "Global routes". I don't know if that belongs in the answer or not; I might be doing something _else_ wrong that's causing that error.  I'll let you add it if you think it matters

Comment: You are right. I considered adding that caveat to answer, but I didn't. Doc mention is [Invalid routes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation?view=net-maui-7.0#invalid-routes).

Answer (score 0):

When you successful navigate to Page A2 or Page B2, you will have 3 pages in the NavigationStack, so remove first 2 pages which is (Page 1 and (Page A1 or Page B1)) then the Page A2 or Page B2 will be the root page.

Comment: While one would expect that to be the case, Shell is more complicated than that, unfortunately. Read carefully the symptom they describe. Regardless of what pages they removed, user was still able to "go back".

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
public Main()
    {
        NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
        NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, false);
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

on the page that you want user not be able to back from.